# Where should I place my credits for my App?

Tags: mobile-application, location

I am almost done with my first app, but I used a font that requires credit.  Where should I put my credits for my app?  Is there a required spot?  I would prefer putting them in my app's description on Google Play, but is that okay?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a section "About" in your app menu, with the description of you/your company (bio, contact details, etc) and the credits for resources used.

EDIT:
Someone made the same question in 2013, take a look at the answers:
[Where to Put Credits for an App](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/40237/where-to-put-credits-for-an-app)

Comment: Since my app is a game, should the about menu be inside of the main menu?  Or is it fine to just put the required credits in my app description?

Comment: I looked at that, but I wasn't sure what to do since my game is a mobile app.

Comment: If you put in the description, app stores SEO can rank your app lower (there are lots of details they take into account, and putting more text, with names that are not related to your game cannot help).

If you put the credits near your company name on a "About" section that shows respect to the people who made the resources you used.